# su - username -c "./script.sh" -> no such file or directory

Tags: bash, rhel, su

We have:

1. a user nico.
2. a folder `/home/nico/script_home` with some bash scripts:

   1. `main.sh`
   2. `subscripta.sh`
   3. `sqlscripta.sh`
3. We connect as root and cd `/home/nico/script_home/`
4. Finally we run `./main.sh`

We get as a result:

1. `subscripta.sh` - no such file or directory
2. The sql script works fine

I noticed that `su - nico -c "pwd"` returns `/home/nico/`
So I tried changing `main.sh` to `./script_home/subscripta.sh` but to no avail.

What is the right syntax to avoid the no such file or directory error when running a script with su -?

```
#main.sh
su - nico -c "./subscripta.sh"
su - nico -c "sqlplus username/pass@some_oracle_db @script_home/sqlscripta.sql"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `su - nico -c "/home/nico/script_home/subscripta.sh"`

Comment: yeah I tried that. I need to run my scripts again to let you guys know what worked or not.

That way it will funnel the answers a bit.

Comment: As I've wrote, put whole path inside "".
You can try of course with some variables like $HOME/script_home/subscripta.sh ...
Question is how this script is built and if there are all paths done as they should be?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `su -` - that does a total login for the user ID, including setting HOME to whatever user ID's home directory is.

Try `su nico -c "./script.sh"`

Also, ensure that script.sh is marked executable.

Comment: Oh nice. This is a great tip. But to run stuff on oracle, I do need to call my oracle's user profile bash_profile has a number of variable exported which allows to call sqlplus etc...